# SVG drop shadow but on a:hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a dropshadow on my SVG element, but only have it appear when it's a:hover. (I used filter tag for the SVG and this is sort of the effect I'm looking for). I read that it's not possible to have inline :hover, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do this. If so how would I implement it on my #sun?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Unica+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <style>
        svg {
            border: 3px solid red;
            
        }
        text {
            font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;
            font-size:25px;
        }
        a#sun {
            fill: #D8A089;
        }

        a:hover#sun {
            fill:#FBA618;
        }

        a:hover#seagull {
            opacity: .8;
        }
        

    </style>
<body>

<svg width="185" height="200"> 
    <defs>
        <filter id="poly" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%"> 
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="15" dy="15" />
          <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" /> 
        </filter>
      </defs>
    <a id="sun" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun" target="_blank"> <!-- where I want the drop shadow to go -->
    <path d="M145,122 a65,65 0 1,0 -115,0" filter="url(#poly)"></path>
    </a>
    <a id="seagull" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gull" target="_blank"> <!-- polygon seagull -->
    <polygon points="0,0 8,16 40,22" style="fill:#494949" />
    <polygon points="8,16 40,22 80,41 45,42 " style="fill:#E3E4DF" />
    <polygon points="80,41 45,42 60,65" style="fill:#EFEFEF" />
    <polygon points="80,41 60,65 70,90 100,70" style="fill:#EBEAE5" />
    <polygon points="80,75 45,95 50,105 110,105" style="fill:#E3E4DF" />
    <polygon points="45,95 10,100 50,105" style="fill:#535257" />
    <polygon points="80,75 110,105 120, 90" style="fill:#EAE9E4" />
    <polygon points="120,90 80,75 110,55 130,60 " style="fill:#EFEFEF" />
    <polygon points="110,55 130,60 132,50" style="fill:#EBEAE5" />
    <polygon points="132,50 130,60 155, 48" style="fill:#E4E5E0" />
    <polygon points="155, 48 165, 35 140, 49.5" style="fill:#505052" />
    <polygon points="120,90 123,80 136,86 135,89 " style="fill:#3F3F3F" />
    <polygon points="136,86 135,89 141,88 " style="fill:#C55F48" />
    </a>

    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
        
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M5 125 l170 0" />
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M25 135 l140 0" />
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M50 145 l90 0" />
    </g>
    <text x="85" y="170" style="fill:black;">R
        <tspan x="85" y="190">C</tspan>
        
      </text>
    

</svg>


</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the filter when you're hovering...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Unica+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <style>
        svg {
            border: 3px solid red;
            
        }
        text {
            font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;
            font-size:25px;
        }
        a#sun {
            fill: #D8A089;
        }

        a:hover#sun {
            fill:#FBA618;
            filter: url(#poly);
        }

        a:hover#seagull {
            opacity: .8;
        }
        

    </style>
<body>

<svg width="185" height="200"> 
    <defs>
        <filter id="poly" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%"> 
          <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="15" dy="15" />
          <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" />
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" /> 
        </filter>
      </defs>
    <a id="sun" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun" target="_blank"> <!-- where I want the drop shadow to go -->
    <path d="M145,122 a65,65 0 1,0 -115,0"></path>
    </a>
    <a id="seagull" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gull" target="_blank"> <!-- polygon seagull -->
    <polygon points="0,0 8,16 40,22" style="fill:#494949" />
    <polygon points="8,16 40,22 80,41 45,42 " style="fill:#E3E4DF" />
    <polygon points="80,41 45,42 60,65" style="fill:#EFEFEF" />
    <polygon points="80,41 60,65 70,90 100,70" style="fill:#EBEAE5" />
    <polygon points="80,75 45,95 50,105 110,105" style="fill:#E3E4DF" />
    <polygon points="45,95 10,100 50,105" style="fill:#535257" />
    <polygon points="80,75 110,105 120, 90" style="fill:#EAE9E4" />
    <polygon points="120,90 80,75 110,55 130,60 " style="fill:#EFEFEF" />
    <polygon points="110,55 130,60 132,50" style="fill:#EBEAE5" />
    <polygon points="132,50 130,60 155, 48" style="fill:#E4E5E0" />
    <polygon points="155, 48 165, 35 140, 49.5" style="fill:#505052" />
    <polygon points="120,90 123,80 136,86 135,89 " style="fill:#3F3F3F" />
    <polygon points="136,86 135,89 141,88 " style="fill:#C55F48" />
    </a>

    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
        
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M5 125 l170 0" />
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M25 135 l140 0" />
        <path stroke-dasharray="20,10,5,5,5,10" stroke-linecap="round" d="M50 145 l90 0" />
    </g>
    <text x="85" y="170" style="fill:black;">R
        <tspan x="85" y="190">C</tspan>
        
      </text>
    

</svg>


</svg>

</body>
</html>
```